# authorize.net showing an alert of encrypt data

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Iam using authorize.net, for payment. But when any of my customer pay from my site, an error occurr says,

You have requested an encrypted page that contains some unencrypted information. 
Information that you see or enter on this page could easily be read by a third party.

and from back end it cuts the amount from customer account, but not return the result, thats  why my site again showing him payment form

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: authorize.net , direct post method

Comment: GUYS where is the answer ....? @Admin please do you have any idea of this question